# AssyncStorage saving data on build

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I'm new at react native and im building a simple app that is saving an array and a value with asyncStorage, but after i build the app using Expo the data persists and is saved on the apk.

How can I wipe the data on installation (a little bit inefficient, but for now it would do it becouse I just will probably have a couple of elements on the array) or on build (I dont know if it is possible) or other way...

That's how i am saving the data.

```
const storeData = async (array) => {
        try {
            console.log("STORED");
            const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(array);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("@sleep_data", jsonValue);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error saving")
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage saved data on your device only. To clear the storage call this from your app:

```js
const clearStorage = () => AsyncStorage.clear()
```

Comment: Oh turns out i din't tested it properly and it is other bug, thank you anyways